# Access the number of users to spawn in locustfile

Tags: locust

I'd like to be able to get access to the value of the -u parameter inside my locust file.

The Runner class gives me the number of concurrently running users but I want to know the value passed to locust via -u.

Update:  Got it

```
@events.init.add_listener
def _(environment, **kwargs):
    print(environment.parsed_options.num_users)
```

Comment: What's the use case for this?

Comment: I want to initialize a module level queue with an item per user.  On start each concurrent user pops an item from the queue.